# Suma en javascript no suma, si no concatena

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema muy básico pero no entiendo que pasa.

En *JavaScript* estoy sumando 2 números, pero en vez de sumarlo los concatena, ejemplo:

> En lugar de 2 + 2 = 4 me da 2 + 2 = 22
> Este es mi código:

```
var terminado = document.getElementById("terminado").value

var tintas = document.getElementById("tintas").value
var valTinta = document.getElementById("valTinta").value
var num = 1
if (terminado == 3) {
    alert(tintas + num)
} else {
    alert(tintas)
}
```

En esta condición me da 31 y debería darme 4.

Comment: puedes usar `parseInt(tintas)` o `+tintas` y se soluciona :)

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que los valores que se obtienen de los elementos html son de tipo string y tienes que convertirlo en número para poder efectuar operaciones matemáticas, sino es como si dijeras que quieres unir dos textos en vez de sumar dos números.

Para convertir un string a número entero y poder efectuar la suma u otro tipo de operaciones debes usar `parseInt()`, este error lo cometes tres veces en el código que proporcionas.

Acá lo corrijo:

```
var terminado = parseInt(document.getElementById("terminado").value)
var tintas = parseInt(document.getElementById("tintas").value)
var valTinta = parseInt(document.getElementById("valTinta").value)

var num = 1
if (terminado == 3) {
    alert(tintas + num)
} else {
    alert(tintas)
}
```

Comment: A si tienes razón nunca pense en que los input los tenia como String y de hecho por eso tengo varios errores que se solucionan con eso.